# bash startup variable expression

Tags: command-line, bash, compiling, environment-variables, bashrc

I have the idea that I would like to add an environment variable ("waitTillReady") to my ~/.bashrc file, such that instead of doing this:

`while [ "$(pidof -s make)" -o "$(pidof -s gcc)" -o "$(pidof -s ld)" ]; do echo "Still compiling..." && sleep 1; done && printf "\n%.0s" {1..20} && date && echo "THINGS ARE READY FOR YOU NOW..."`

I want to be able to do this:
`$waitTillReady && echo "THINGS ARE READY FOR YOU NOW..."`

I tried to edit my ~/.bashrc file like with different combinations of the following:

```
...
export waitTillReady="while [ "$(pidof -s make)" -o "$(pidof -s gcc)" -o "$(pidof -s ld)" ]; do echo "Still compiling..." && sleep 1; done && printf "\n%.0s" {1..20} && date"
...
```

E.g. I tried to enclose everything insider a single quote ' and I tried to escape the \" in the middle... Could anyone please help and tell what I should write in the ~/.bashrc file, after the "export waitTillReady=" line?

I would be grateful to hear any suggestions/ideas (and maybe an explanation of what I'm doing wrong), thanks!

Comment: you want an alias or a function, not export...

Comment: Oh, thanks - I see... So it isn't possible to make as an EXPORT (not that I absolutely want that, just asking of curiosity) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the syntax was correct, `export` would run your code only once, when your terminal starts and sets the result as an environment variable, which you can call using `$waitTillReady`.

You need an `alias` or maybe easier a `shell function`.

Put this in your `.bashrc`:

```
waitTillReady() {
    while pgrep '^(make|gcc|ld)$' &>/dev/null; do
        echo "Still compiling..." && sleep 1
    done && printf "\n%.0s" {1..20} && date
}
```

Then after next start of your terminal you can use it like it was a command:

```
waitTillReady; do_something
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Just to be clear - there's no way to make something like I originally started out with work, right (with "EXPORT ... [something]")? Because of some shell expansion stuff or...?

Comment: you would need [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) like this: `export variableName=$(command)`, but like I said, this will run only once when the terminal starts.

Comment: ok: "... will run only once when the terminal starts" - that's not good enough :-) Thanks, I've marked as answered and am very happy now, it works for me with both the function - and the alias... It'll make things a bit easier, thanks.